# How to build a Sorted Bar Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a sorted bar chart (similar to the one presented here: http://flowingdata.com/2008/08/19/3-worthwhile-alternatives-to-the-pie-chart/). When I run the code below, I get something very similar, but the bars aren't sorted. How can I sort the bars so that the one with the highest frequency is at the top of the chart?

```
cat = c("CatA", "CatB", "CatC", "CatB", "CatB", "CatB", "CatB", "CatB", "CatB", "CatB")
dat = data.frame(Category = cat)

qplot(factor(Category), data=dat, geom="bar") + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: You need to order your factor levels.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I am asking how to order a simple histogram with a data.frame of a single dimension.

Comment: @Martin it is a duplicate in that any time you use the words [sort and chart/plot](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/) you (almost always) need to reorder the factor levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
dat$Category <- factor(dat$Category, levels=names(sort(tapply(dat$Category, dat$Category, length))))
```

And see my blog post on this: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it with base graphics, too:

```
barplot(sort(table(dat)), horiz=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea sgibb! But I need to stick to the look and feel of gpplot2 charts... :(

Answer (score 1):

Roman is right, you need to get your factor levels in the right order. Using @sgibbs logic, something like this will work (excusing my total unfamiliarity with `ggplot`:

```
qplot(factor(Category,levels=names(sort(table(cat)))), data=dat, geom="bar") + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip()
```